# if condition with ternary operator not returning true or false

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am comparing 2 object properties in Nodejs

```
 if(alteredItem.main != (result.main)?result.main:"NULL"){
```

I am using debug mode in VSCODE so when I check:

```
alteredItem.main = "232"
result.main = "232"
```

So, I am expecting the result of the above condition to be `False` but my debug console shows that the value is :

```
"NULL"
```

If I remove the ternary operator and change the condition to:

```
if(alteredItem.main != result.main){
```

this does return `false`.

Why does it return `"NULL"` when I use the ternary operator?

Comment: It is returning false. When false, it's returning the NULL you told it to.

Comment: `if(alteredItem.main != result.main)` would return true or false as you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing an `if` statement and a ternary expression. You should do either/or, but not both:

Option 1:

```js
if(alteredItem.main != result.main){
  return false;
} else {
  return 'NULL'
}
```

Option 2:

```js
// It's unclear from your question what you're expecting
// the return value to be, this assumes you want to
// return either `false` or `'NULL'`
return alteredItem.main != result.main ? false : 'NULL';
```